# Displaying one column from inner query

Tags: sql, heidisql

Please help me solve this:

```
SELECT a.prs_code,
       a.cc,
       b.description
FROM   idp_inpadoc_prs_cc a,
       idp_inpadoc_cat_desc b
WHERE  a.ID = b.ID
       AND a.prs_code IN (SELECT prs_code
                          FROM   tls221_inpadoc_prs c,
                                 tls201_appln d
                          WHERE  c.appln_id = d.appln_id
                                 AND c.appln_id IN ( '1', '2' ));
```

In this query, along with `prs_code`, `cc`, `description`, I also want to display the corresponding `appln_id`. How can I do this? Kindly help. Thanks! :)

Comment: why so many RDBMS tags? which one are you using?

Comment: I'm using HeidiSQL.

Comment: I've added the tag for it. Please remember that when you tag SQL related, don't use mixed RDBMS-related tags, since Oracle and MySQL as you had before, have some differences in syntax.

Comment: I'm sorry I'll keep that in mind from now on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so when you start looking at transforming this to joins this should do the same as your query because `appln_id` is on both the `tls221_inadoc_prs` and the `tsl201_appln` tables so you don't actually need the later table if the `tls221_inadoc_prs.appln_id` is a foreign key to `tls201_appln.appln_id` meaning that if the value is in `tls221_inadoc_prs` then it also must be in `tls201_appln`

```
SELECT a.prs_code,
       a.cc,
       b.description
      ,c.appln_id
FROM
    idp_inpadoc_prs_cc a
    INNER JOIN idp_inpadoc_cat_desc b
    ON a.ID = b.ID
    INNER JOIN tls221_inpadoc_prs c
    ON a.prs_code = c.prs_code
    AND d.appln_id IN (1,2)
```

If it is not a foreign key you can simply add another join as well:

```
SELECT a.prs_code,
       a.cc,
       b.description
      ,c.appln_id
FROM
    idp_inpadoc_prs_cc a
    INNER JOIN idp_inpadoc_cat_desc b
    ON a.ID = b.ID
    INNER JOIN tls221_inpadoc_prs c
    ON a.prs_code = c.prs_code
    AND c.appln_id IN ( '1', '2' )
    INNER JOIN tls201_appln d
    ON c.appln_id = d.appln_id
```

Comment: After adding a distinct in the select, this seems to work! Thanks! You are right. tls201 is not needed. appln_id connects the tables tls221 and tls201.